# Gradle dependency downloads but packages aren't available in project

Tags: java, gradle

I published a small library of mine to a free maven hosting service, and am using that package in another project. I've done this before without issue but something isn't working this time.

Gradle finds the file just fine, and downloads it I assume. I know this because any change to the URL, package name, or version, and Gradle throws the "can't find the dep in any of these places" error.

However, any `import` of the packages in this JAR error, saying it can't find the package. IntelliJ, when I refresh gradle deps, also doesn't show my library in the "External Libraries" section.

Here's my gradle.build for the project I'm using the library in:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {

    maven { url = 'https://repo.repsy.io/mvn/viveleroi/tileowner' }
}

group = project.property("group")
version = project.property("version")

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'network.darkhelmet.tileowner:tileowner:1.0.0'
}

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-parameters"]
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
}
```

The test class:

```
import network.darkhelmet.tileowner.TileOwner;

public class Demo {}
```

Gradle says it's on the classpath:

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- network.darkhelmet.tileowner:tileowner:1.0.0

compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
\--- network.darkhelmet.tileowner:tileowner:1.0.0 (n)
```

I've downloaded the published jar of my library from that repository, unzipped it, and have confirmed all files are in there as expected.

Here's the build.gradle of my library project:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.github.rodionmoiseev.gradle.plugins', name: 'idea-utils', version: '0.2'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "7.0.0"
    id "xyz.jpenilla.run-paper" version "1.0.6"
    id 'maven-publish'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'idea-utils'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

processResources {
    filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
        "apiversion": project.property("apiversion"),
        "version"   : project.property("version")
    ]
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url = "https://repo.aikar.co/content/groups/aikar/" }
    maven { url = 'https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
}

group = project.property("group")
version = project.property("version")
targetCompatibility = sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.18-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'co.aikar:acf-bukkit:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-parameters"]
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
}

jar {
    actions = []
    dependsOn = []
    dependsOn('shadowJar')
}

shadowJar {
    relocate 'co.aikar.commands', 'network.darkhelmet.tileowner.acf'
    relocate 'co.aikar.locales', 'network.darkhelmet.tileowner.locales'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        shadow(MavenPublication) { publication ->
            project.shadow.component(publication)
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'repsy'
            url = 'https://repo.repsy.io/mvn/viveleroi/tileowner'
            credentials(PasswordCredentials)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you look inside the ,m2 dir and check everything is correct? That is the jar is in the correct place and all the other paths like ~/,m2/tileowner/tileowner/1.0.0/<non empty jar> exist ?

Comment: No, looking now and I don't see it. Although I also don't see an unrelated library with the same package structure that I've used just fine there either.

Comment: One difference I notice is the repo URL is longer for this library than my last one. `https://repsy.io/mvn/viveleroi/tileowner/network/darkhelmet/tileowner/tileowner/1.0.0/` vs `https://repsy.io/mvn/viveleroi/oracle-api/network/darkhelmet/oracle-api/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/` - gradle doesn't complain so idk if that would be a problem but the second address works

Comment: Ok the URL issue was because my package name on the published lib was longer than it needed to be. However even after fixing that and updating my gradle.build, the code is not available locally.

Comment: I don't think something missing from m2 is entirely the problem though, because another app I have uses `compileOnly 'network.darkhelmet:oracle-api:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'` and it compiles fine, and there's no `network` directory in the `.m2/repositories/` path. I do see that project in the external libraries list in IntelliJ though, and I don't see that with this library.

Comment: Gradle even lists my lib in the "compile classpath for source set 'main'`: `+-- network.darkhelmet:tileowner:1.0.0`

Comment: Ok, it definitely is related to the library publishing the `-all` shaded jar. I removed the shading and re-published and now it works.